# Share internet from ethernet to ethernet, Windows To Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu-10.04, connection-sharing, crossover-cable

I have two computers on my desk, and my router is across the room. I have 1 long ethernet cable connecting my windows 7 PC to the internet. I've been using wireless on my Ubuntu laptop, but this is getting irksome. So, I'd like to connect my laptop to the internet through its ethernet port by connecting a crossover cable from my laptop to my PC's second ethernet port.

I've googled a bit and the recommendations seem to be to use ICS (which just seems to completely kill my connection) or to bridge the connections (which doesn't kill the connection on my windows computer, but I'm then unsure how to configure things so that my ubuntu computer has a connection).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bridged connection is the better solution. If you set up the bridge properly, and set your Ubuntu computer to automatically get an IP address from DHCP, it should work. Connection bridging in Windows usually forward DHCP requests to the router the Windows computer is attached to, and so the bridged computer appears to the router as if it were its own computer. Does this work for you?

Comment: if it doesn't just use a static IP

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I think I just needed someone to tell me what I was doing was sane before I went through with trying all the little possible things that could be messing it out :)

Comment: Glad that worked then. Happy computing!